# Passing the parameter via an automatically generated JavaScript link to the controller

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem with passing the parameter via the link to the controller. The view in which I have a problem is to dynamically display the list of users, along with the possibility of searching for them. I did this part in js and it works fine. In this functionality in js I generate a link to the buttons, so that later, after pressing the button, you can save the selection in the database. Each link has an assigned user ID and user group ID. My problem is that when I press the button, nothing happens.

The following code represents the functionality described above. I would be very grateful for your help.

```js
@if(ViewData[Enums.States.UserSelectWindow.ToString()].ToString() == "True")
 {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#UserlistCollectionId").css('height', $("#WindowUserSelectId").height() + 'px');

    let users = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(UserModel.GetUsers()));

        function Clear() {
            $("#UserlistCollectionId").empty();
        }

        function FillAll(users) {
            Clear();
            for (user of users) {
                $("#UserlistCollectionId").append('<li class="list-group-item"><div class="row justify-content-between"><div class="col-auto">' + user.name + '</div><div class="col-auto"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" asp-action="AddUserToGroup" asp-controller="Settings" asp-route-groupId=@Model.Group.Id asp-route-userId='+user.id+'>Wybierz</a></div></div></li>');
            }
        }

        FillAll(users);

        $("#SearchInputId").keyup(function () {
            Clear();
            let searchValue = $("#SearchInputId").val();
            if (searchValue === "")
                FillAll(users);
            else {
                for (user of users) {
                    if (user.name.includes(searchValue)) {
                        $("#UserlistCollectionId").append('<li class="list-group-item"><div class="row justify-content-between"><div class="col-auto">' + user.name + '</div><div class="col-auto"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" asp-route-groupId=@Model.Group.Id asp-route-userId='+user.id+'>Wybierz</a></div></div></li>');
                    }
                }
            }
    });
</script>
 }
```

In the above code, automatic link generation is performed using JQuery as follows:

```js
$("#UserlistCollectionId").append('<li class="list-group-item"><div class="row justify-content-between"><div class="col-auto">' + user.name + '</div><div class="col-auto"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" asp-route-groupId=@Model.Group.Id asp-route-userId='+user.id+'>Wybierz</a></div></div></li>');
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. In the inspection of the page you can see that the tag "a" does not have the attribute "href", only automatically puts all the code in quotes:
[Screen of the html fragment in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB17H.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need read [the doc about what does asp-route-{value} generate the url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0#asp-route-value):

Any value occupying the `{value}` placeholder is interpreted as a potential route parameter. If a default route isn't found, this route prefix is appended to the generated href attribute as a request parameter and value
(`/home/index?value=aaa`). Otherwise, it's substituted in the route template. More explantion you could refer to the document.

Secondly, you do not specify the controller and action name, so the url will generate depending on your request url. That is to say, if the tag helper exists in `Home/Privacy.cshtml`, it will generate to:`href="/home/privacy?value=aa"`.

Finally, Tag Helpers are interpreted. In other words, Razor must see them as actual tags in order to replace them. So what you did in js will not follow the tag helper generation principle, it's just a JS string. You need change the url like below:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="/home/index?groupId=' +@Model.Group.Id+'&userId=' + user.id+'">Wybierz</a>
```

If the url matches the default route template, the url may like below：

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="/home/index/' +@Model.Group.Id+'/' + user.id+'">Wybierz</a>
```